# (Auto) Run xrandr on login?

Tags: 14.04, display, resolution

I often attach a monitor with my laptop's VGA port, however the resolution is not optimized so I run:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1440x900_59.90" 106.29 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 901 904 932 -HSync +Vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_59.90
```

to achieve better resolutions and it works just fine. However I want to automate this (safely) that when I open my laptop the monitor resolution will be automatically optimized (I am not particular with the login screen, its fine even at that point resolution is low)

Comment: Almost identical situation: would this suit you (with a few changes): http://askubuntu.com/questions/527331/make-external-display-resolution-auto-set/527362#527362? It is a simple way to correctly set your second screen automatically. Leave a comment if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a .sh file and attach it make a .desktop file that runs  it then add it to the startup applications.